# Servlet class org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet is not a jakarta.servlet.Servlet

Tags: servlets, jetty, restlet

What could be causing this error?

```
    Caused by: jakarta.servlet.UnavailableException: Servlet class org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet is not a jakarta.servlet.Servlet
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.checkServletType (ServletHolder.java:499)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart (ServletHolder.java:377)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:96)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.lambda$initialize$2 (ServletHandler.java:699)
        at java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end (SortedOps.java:357)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto (AbstractPipeline.java:485)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto (AbstractPipeline.java:474)
        at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining (StreamSpliterators.java:312)
        at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining (Streams.java:735)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach (ReferencePipeline.java:658)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:724)
```

I'm running the web app from `mvn jetty:run` plugin

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> jakarta.servlet.UnavailableException: Servlet class [...] is not a jakarta.servlet.Servlet

The `jakarta.servlet.Servlet` is part of Servlet API version 5.0 which in turn is part of Jakarta EE version 9. This can thus only mean that the servlet class specified in `[...]` is NOT compiled against Servlet API version 5.0, but against an older version.

You have 2 options:

1. Upgrade the servlet class specified in `[...]` to a Servlet API version 5.0 compatible one.
2. Or, downgrade the servlet container from Servlet API version 5.0 to a previous version, at least the one matching the target Servlet API version of the servlet class specified in `[...]`.

The technical reason is that during the step from Java/Jakarta EE 8 to Jakarta EE 9 all `javax.*` packages have been renamed to `jakarta.*` packages. So there is no backwards compatibility anymore since Jakarta EE 9.

When we translate the above facts to your specific situation, your only option is to downgrade the Jetty servlet container to a Servlet 4.0 compatible version. This is because the 3rd party library "Restlet" has currently no Servlet 5.0 compatible version available at all. According to Jetty's version table, Jetty 11.x is Jakarta EE 9 targeted, so you need Jetty version 10.x or older.

Alternatively, you can drop Restlet altogether and use Jersey instead. It has currently a Jakarta EE 9 compatible version available.

#### See also:

- [Jetty versions](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/what-jetty-version.html)
- [Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.servlet.Filter on Maven/Jersey web service while running on Tomcat 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62927426/getting-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-jakarta-servlet-filter-on-maven-jersey/)

Comment: Already have `        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>`

Comment: quarks, it doesn't work that way. The target runtime itself must **actually** also be that servlet API version. The `provided` entry in `pom.xml` doesn't magically change the target runtime to the expected version. You can still run it against Jetty 11.x and end up into the specified trouble. As explained in the answer, you need to physically downgrade Jetty to 10.x in order to comply the expectation as specified in pom.xml.

Comment: Oh shoot, you're right. Apparently in my POM the `${jetty.version}` was removed causing it to fetch the version 11, my bad.

Comment: Can happen to the best.

Comment: you may be interested to give a comment on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64118991/transactional-objects-over-rmi too

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to run a Maven application inside a Wildfly server

I installed [20.0.1.Final](https://www.wildfly.org/downloads/), the last version before Jakarta