# Tomcat 10.0.4 doesn't load servlets (@WebServlet classes) with 404 error

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, servlets, tomcat10

I'm having a problem with my first Web Application. I use IntelliJ as IDE and Tomcat as Webserver.
Every servlet I've tried to acces, throws an 404 Error. Even if I copy some youtube tutorials, which seems to work like a charm.

The button in the form sends me to: http://localhost:8080/IUBHQuiz/login

Can you tell me whats wrong? I am going nuts.

**login.java**

```
package com.example.IUBHQuiz;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

@WebServlet("/login")
public class login extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String email = request.getParameter("fmail");
        String pass = request.getParameter("fpw");

        if(email.equals("j") && pass.equals("j"))
        {
            RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("/main.jsp");
            rs.forward(request, response);
        }
        else
        {
            out.println("Username or Password incorrect");

            RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
            rs.include(request, response);
        }

        out.close();
    }
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>IUBH Quiz</title>
    <link href="./resources/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="image-container">
           <img src="./resources/images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
        </div>
        <div class="Login">
            <h1>Willkommen beim IUBH-Quiz!</h1>
            <form action="login" method="post">
                E-Mail:<input type="text" id="fmail" name="fmail"><br><br>
                Passwort: <input type="password" id="fpw" name="fpw"><br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Log In" class="button">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="Links">
            <a href="#">Passwort vergessen</a>
            <a href="#">Registrieren</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
</web-app>
```

Comment: What Tomcat version do you use? There were some issues with Tomcat 10, please see if it works with Tomcat 9.

Comment: You've got to be kidding me. I spent the whole day searching for a solution and almost gone crazy. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue while reproducing [the problem reported at IntelliJ IDEA forums](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010562679-Servlet-error).

It didn't work with Tomcat 10 for the reasons [described in the answer by Piotr P. Karwasz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66808062/104891), but it works just fine with Tomcat 9.0.44 and earlier versions.

Comment: Works with all 9.0.x versions as the page [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) mentions that it is compatible with Servlet spec 4.0

Answer (score 30):

For copyright reasons the Servlet 5.0 API (implemented by Tomcat 10) and the Servlet 4.0 API (implemented by Tomcat 9) are incompatible: the API namespace changed from `javax.*` to `jakarta.*`. This can manifest in many ways:

1. Software written for Servlet 4.0 does not compile against the API jars from Tomcat 10: cf. [Servlet 5.0 JAR throws compile error on javax.servlet.* but Servlet 4.0 JAR does not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64387472/11748454),
2. Servlet 4.0 applications which use a `web.xml` descriptor throw a lot of `ClassNotFoundException`s and don't start: cf. [Tomcat 10.x throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on javax/servlet/ServletRequestListener](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66711660/11748454).
3. Servlet 4.0 applications which use a `web.xml` descriptor log a *"X is not a jakarta.servlet.Servlet"* error: cf. [Servlet class org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet is not a jakarta.servlet.Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64117697/11748454).
4. Servlet 4.0 applications which use annotations to declare servlets stop working, as **in your case**,
5. Servlet 4.0 applications which rely on a `ServletContainerInitializer` (like Spring and Spring Boot applications) don't start: cf. [Deploying Spring MVC 5 on Tomcat 10 … deployment problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66217350/11748454)

The last one is the hardest to diagnose: no errors are written to the log files, but the application doesn't work. The reason behind this behavior is that `@javax.servlet.WebServlet` annotations are ignored: the server is scanning for `@jakarta.servlet.WebServlet`.

Since all three problems have the same cause, the solutions provided to the aforementioned questions all work. In this specific case I would advise to use the [Tomcat Migration Tool for Jakarta EE](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-10.cgi).

**Remark**: The [Tomcat download site](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-10.cgi) features a warning, that unfortunately many people don't notice:

> Users of Tomcat 10 onwards should be aware that, as a result of the move from Java EE to Jakarta EE as part of the transfer of Java EE to the Eclipse Foundation, the primary package for all implemented APIs has changed from javax.* to jakarta.*. This will almost certainly require code changes to enable applications to migrate from Tomcat 9 and earlier to Tomcat 10 and later.

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks for the detailed explanation. I've linked your answer from mine so that it's easier to find. I guess almost no one would read the migration guide or warnings before downloading the server to try it out, so this question would become extremely popular.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer.