# Why is upgrading to Tomcat 10.0.5 causing spring boot to shutdown after boot?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, tomcat10

I have a spring boot project and I am trying to use Tomcat 10 embedded instead of Tomcat 7. I add the following to my POM...

```
<properties>
    <tomcat.version>10.0.5</tomcat.version>
    ...
</properties>
```

Then I run the same command I was running before...

```
mvn clean package -U && java -cp target\my.jar;props -Dloader.main=com.my.Main org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```

But now it just starts and then shuts itself down. The final messages are...

```
2021-05-13 15:35:42.105  INFO 10084 --- [           main] com.my.Main                   : Started Main in 42.918 seconds (JVM running for 44.009)
2021-05-13 15:35:42.190  INFO 10084 --- [extShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

Why would this happen and how can I upgrade without this side effect?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Servlet 5.0 JAR throws compile error on javax.servlet.\* but Servlet 4.0 JAR does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64387472/servlet-5-0-jar-throws-compile-error-on-javax-servlet-but-servlet-4-0-jar-does)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Tomcat 10 is a Jakarta EE 9 servlet container. It basically means, that all `javax.*` packages were renamed to `jakarta.*` for copyright reasons (Oracle didn't allow the Eclipse Foundation to use the `javax.*` names).

Spring Boot 2 and Spring 5 support only the previous Java EE 8 specification, you need to use Spring Boot 3 and Spring 6 for Tomcat 10 support. Alternatively you can pass Spring libraries through the [Apache Tomcat Migration Tool](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-migration.cgi) or downgrade to Tomcat 9.0.

#### See also

- [Tomcat 10.0.4 doesn't load servlets (@WebServlet classes) with 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66806582/11748454)

Comment: confirmed "<tomcat.version>9.0.45</tomcat.version>" works