# Tomcat Server problem with my SAPUI5 Project on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, server, sapui5

so I have been having this problem for a few days now. I created a SAPUI5 project on Eclipse and created a tomcat server to run the project on localhost. But when I click on Run As -> Run on Server I get this one here:  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xhxh6.png)

I have already tried out a few things to fix it, for example when I run server on localhost the front page is the tomcat server webpage. But when I try to run the project it doesn't work right. Can you help me with this issue please.

Comment: What's deployed to the root of your application? Which of the configured "welcome-file"s did you provide? *Why should this URL work?*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tomcat 10.0.4 doesn't load servlets (@WebServlet classes) with 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66806582/tomcat-10-0-4-doesnt-load-servlets-webservlet-classes-with-404-error)

Comment: SAPUI5 with eclipse is now outdated since years - don't work with eclipse. Update your project to ui5-tooling and use the BAS or visual studio code.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I switched to visual studio code and I do not have a server problem anymore.