# How to create a Spring Boot application and run it as .war in Tomcat?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

### Summary

I'm trying to create a basic Spring Boot application from scratch, build a .war file and run it in Tomcat. I achieved to run it in Intellij, but it is not running in Tomcat.

### Reproduce

I explain in the following, how to reproduce my issue. Please write a comment if I'm missing anything relevant.

#### How to create the project?

Generate the project on https://start.spring.io/ using the following options

[image: Spring Initializr Options]

Click the button `Generate`. A file `demo.zip` is downloaded. Extract it as directory `demo`. It should contain the following files:

```
├── HELP.md
├── demo.iml
├── mvnw
├── mvnw.cmd
├── pom.xml
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── com
    │   │       └── example
    │   │           └── demo
    │   │               ├── DemoApplication.java
    │   │               └── ServletInitializer.java
    │   └── resources
    │       ├── application.properties
    │       ├── static
    │       └── templates
    └── test
        └── java
            └── com
                └── example
                    └── demo
                        └── DemoApplicationTests.java
```

---

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

src/main/java/com/example/demo/DemoApplication.java

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

src/main/java/com/example/demo/ServletInitializer.java

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(DemoApplication.class);
    }

}
```

`src/main/resources/application.properties` is empty

---

Add a file `src/main/java/com/example/demo/HelloWorldController.java` with content

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloWorldController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
    }
}
```

#### How to run the project in Intellij?

Open and load the maven project in Intellij. In the menu select `Run` and `Run 'DemoApplication'`. You should see something like this in the console:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.2)

2021-07-09 17:31:07.447  INFO 7245 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication using Java 1.8.0_292 on MY_HOST with PID 7245 (/path/to/demo/target/classes started by USER in /path/to/demo)
2021-07-09 17:31:07.451  INFO 7245 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-07-09 17:31:08.636  INFO 7245 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-07-09 17:31:08.647  INFO 7245 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-07-09 17:31:08.648  INFO 7245 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.48]
2021-07-09 17:31:08.720  INFO 7245 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-07-09 17:31:08.720  INFO 7245 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1205 ms
2021-07-09 17:31:09.214  INFO 7245 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-07-09 17:31:09.229  INFO 7245 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 2.89 seconds (JVM running for 3.783)
```

Open http://localhost:8080/ in your browser. You should see

```
Greetings from Spring Boot!
```

#### How to build the .war in Intellij?

Select `View > Tool Windows > Maven` in the menu and run lifecycles `clean` and `package`

[image: Maven Tool Window with highlighted lifecycles]

Among other files, a file `target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war` is created.

#### How to run the project in Tomcat?

> **Note:** I'm using Docker in the following to make the environment as reproducible as possible. However, I also tried Tomcat installed on another Mac using brew and got the same issue.

Run in the terminal (in the project root directory)

```
docker run --rm -p 8081:8080 \
  -v ${PWD}/target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/demo.war \
  tomcat:10-jdk8
```

You should get output similar to this:

```
09-Jul-2021 16:44:19.312 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/10.0.8
09-Jul-2021 16:44:19.315 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jun 25 2021 23:05:41 UTC
09-Jul-2021 16:44:19.315 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 10.0.8.0
09-Jul-2021 16:44:19.315 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
09-Jul-2021 16:44:19.315 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            5.10.25-linuxkit
09-Jul-2021 16:44:19.315 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
09-Jul-2021 16:44:19.316 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/local/openjdk-8/jre
09-Jul-2021 16:44:19.316 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_292-b10
09-Jul-2021 16:44:19.316 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
09-Jul-2021 16:44:19.316 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/local/tomcat
09-Jul-2021 16:44:19.316 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/local/tomcat
09-Jul-2021 16:44:19.320 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
09-Jul-2021 16:44:19.320 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
09-Jul-2021 16:44:19.320 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
09-Jul-2021 16:44:19.320 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
09-Jul-2021 16:44:19.321 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
09-Jul-2021 16:44:19.321 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
09-Jul-2021 16:44:19.321 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat
09-Jul-2021 16:44:19.321 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat
09-Jul-2021 16:44:19.321 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp
09-Jul-2021 16:44:19.335 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.30] using APR version [1.6.5].
09-Jul-2021 16:44:19.335 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true], UDS [true].
09-Jul-2021 16:44:19.339 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019]
09-Jul-2021 16:44:19.821 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
09-Jul-2021 16:44:19.844 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [769] milliseconds
09-Jul-2021 16:44:19.898 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
09-Jul-2021 16:44:19.898 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.0.8]
09-Jul-2021 16:44:19.945 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/demo.war]
09-Jul-2021 16:44:21.248 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
09-Jul-2021 16:44:21.315 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/demo.war] has finished in [1,369] ms
09-Jul-2021 16:44:21.321 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
09-Jul-2021 16:44:21.339 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [1494] milliseconds
```

> **Note:** I expect that the log of my app, i.e.
>
> ```
>   .   ____          _            __ _ _
>  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
> ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
>  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
>   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
>  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
>  :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.2)
>
> ...
> ```
>
> appears here too, but it is missing.

Open http://localhost:8081/demo/ in your browser. I expect to see

```
Greetings from Spring Boot!
```

but I get

[image: 404 page]

---

What am I missing in my project or Tomcat configuration/code? How to run my Spring Boot application as .war in Tomcat?

Comment: That is also the reason why the Docker image [`tomcat:latest`](https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat) is a Tomcat 9.0 running on an OpenJDK 11 JVM.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/66808062/104891 explain why you get 404 with Tomcat 10?

Comment: @piotr-p-karwasz Yes, using `tomcat:9-jdk8` instead of `tomcat:10-jdk8` is working. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thanks for pointing to an explanation.

Comment: Could I have figured this out by the logs or only by guessing/suspecting that the Tomcat version may be an issue?

Comment: I have a bigger project (private) that behaves similar, but does not work with Tomcat 9 either. I searched a lot, but I'm still in the dark, why it is not working/running.

Comment: @maiermic: The logs are probably empty, since Spring uses a `javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer`. Since Tomcat 10 does not handle it, the only thing you might notice is the lack of logs.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, running Tomcat 9 instead of 10 works

```
docker run --rm -p 8081:8080 \
  -v ${PWD}/target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/demo.war \
  tomcat:9-jdk8
```