# Building WAR file of maven project with vaadin

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, vaadin, war

I'm trying to build a WAR file for my maven project which I used vaadin framework inside. When I run project in eclipse with jetty:run project runs smoothly. But when I tried to create a WAR file and deploy it to Apcahe Tomcat 10 I get the 404 Not Found error. When I searched online nearly every solution about the index.jsp file but I don't have an index.jsp file in my project. Packaging WAR is added in my pom.xml file. In mavens site the proper maven directory shows as follows [image]

But my directory is not same with the one here. I don't have web.xml and index.jsp file. It's probably because of the vaadin framework but I cant find a way to deploy project. Can anyone help me about this problem?

Thank you.

my pom.xml file looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example.project</groupId>
<artifactId>projectProgram</artifactId>
<name>projectProgram</name>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

    <vaadin.version>14.6.6</vaadin.version>
    <jetty.version>9.4.15.v20190215</jetty.version>
</properties>

<pluginRepositories>
    <!-- Repository needed for using Vaadin prerelease versions
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
        <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
     -->
</pluginRepositories>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-addons</id>
        <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <!-- Repository needed for using Vaadin prerelease versions <repository>
        <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
        <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
    </repository>
    -->
</repositories>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Webjars are only needed when running in Vaadin 13 compatibility mode -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.vaadin.webjar</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.insites</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymer</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymerelements</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.webcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-testbench</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Added to provide logging output as Flow uses -->
    <!-- the unbound SLF4J no-operation (NOP) logger implementation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <defaultGoal>jetty:run</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>1</scanIntervalSeconds>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>it</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <stopPort>9966</stopPort>
                        <stopKey>stopit</stopKey>
                        <scanIntervalSeconds>-1</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>start-jetty</id>
                            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>start</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>stop-jetty</id>
                            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>stop</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <!-- Production mode is activated using -Pproduction -->
        <id>production</id>
        <properties>
            <vaadin.productionMode>true</vaadin.productionMode>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>flow-server-production-mode</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: How did you create the project? And how does your pom.xml look like?

Comment: Vaadin does not work with Tomcat 10 or any Servlet 5.0 container. Check, e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66806582/11748454) for the reason. Your JSPs on the other hand should work if they don't contain scriptlets.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz if I downgrade the tomcat version to 9 will it be okay or this is a general problem in vaadin projects? I don't have jsp files in my project.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli i updated the question and added the pom.xml file

Comment: @Jiraiya: yes, Tomcat 9.0 will work. There is a disruptive change propagating through the Java EE community (cf. [this article](https://eclipse-foundation.blog/2020/12/08/jakarta-ee-9-delivers-the-big-bang/)). Software libraries are either pre-Jakarta EE 9 or post-Jakarta EE 9. You can not mix them. Vaadin, as most libraries, still uses Java EE 8/Jakarta EE 8.

Comment: How did you create this project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @PiotrP.Karwasz I downgrade the tomcat version to Tomcat9 from Tomcat10 and that solved the problem.