# HTTP Status 404 – Not Found error in Netbeans

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

After request http://localhost:8080/Demo/ and I got the error "HTTP Status 404 – Not Found". What is the problem? I use Tomcat 10 .How to fix it!!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcoOp.png

applicationContext.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:flow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
       xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
       xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.3.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-5.3.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-5.3.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-5.3.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-5.3.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-5.3.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi-1.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-5.3.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-5.3.xsd
">
    <context:annocation-config />
</beans>
```

index.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Welcome Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

DispatcherSelvetIntializer.java

```
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;


public class DispatcherServeltIntializer extends 
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{
            WebApplicationContextConfig.class
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
    
}
```

WebApplicationContextConfig.java

```
package com.mycompany.configs;

import com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic.AALOAD;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

/**
 *
 * @author khoin
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mycompany.controllers")
public class WebApplicationContextConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{
    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
    
    
}
```

HomeControllers.java

```
package com.mycompany.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
@Controller
public class HomeControllers {
    
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>Demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Demo</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tomcat 10.0.4 doesn't load servlets (@WebServlet classes) with 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66806582/tomcat-10-0-4-doesnt-load-servlets-webservlet-classes-with-404-error)

Comment: Have you tried `http://localhost:8080/`?

Comment: Yes I tried but error

Comment: At this time no Spring application will work with Tomcat 10.0 (or any Jakarta EE 9 servers).