# .war on tomcat on docker, 404 on servlet

Tags: docker, tomcat, servlets

I finally found the motivation to work with Docker : I tried to deploy a basic "hello-world" servlet, on a tomcat running on a docker container.

This servlet works perfectly when I run it on the Tomcat started by intelliJ.

But when I use it with Docker, using this Dockerfile

```
FROM tomcat:latest
ADD example.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["/usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh", "run"]
```

And I build/start the image/container:

```
docker build -t example .

docker run -p 8090:8080 example
```

The index.jsp is displayed correctly at localhost:8090/example/, but I get a 404 when trying to access the servlet at localhost:8090/example/hello-servlet

At the same time, I can access localhost:8080/example/hello-servlet, when my non dockerized tomcat runs, and it works well.

Here is the servlet code :

```
package io.bananahammock.bananahammock_backend;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;

@WebServlet(name = "helloServlet", value = "/hello-servlet")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private String message;

    public void init() {
        message = "Hello World!";
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><body>");
        out.println("<h1>" + message + "</h1>");
        out.println("</body></html>");
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since August 31, 2021 ([this commit](https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat/commit/55d8abb2b3852e7a2a734b1943c8433c3944d88d#diff-9dd720074107975da3d3140d5e27deb1e3870cb10fd74029ded8d6e1efe98346)) the Docker image `tomcat:latest` uses Tomcat 10 (see the list of [available tags](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/tomcat/README.md#supported-tags-and-respective-dockerfile-links)).

As you are probably aware, software which uses the `javax.*` namespace does not work on Jakarta EE 9 servers such as Tomcat 10 (see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66806582/11748454)). Therefore:

- if it is a new project, migrate to the `jakarta.*` namespace and test everything on Tomcat 10 or higher,
- if it is a legacy project, use another Docker image, e.g. the `tomcat:9` tag.

Comment: `FROM tomcat:9` worked perfectly. Thanks. (`FROM tomcat:8.0`  and `FROM tomcat` didn't )

Comment: The `tomcat` tag is the same as `tomcat:latest`, so it will not work. Tomcat 8.0 reached end-of-life a couple of years ago, so you should use `tomcat:8` (which is an alias for Tomcat 8.5) instead.