# Flowable Open Source REST API Setup in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu-18.04, flowable

I followed instructions given in [Flowable Getting Started Guide](https://wwv.flowable.com/open-source/docs/bpmn/ch02-GettingStarted/#setting-up-the-rest-application) to setup Flowable REST API on Ubuntu 18.04. After running `sudo ./catalina run`, I do get Apache Tomcat up and running on port 8080. However, when I try REST APIs of `flowable-rest`, I get a 404 error.

```
java --version
java 17.0.1 2021-10-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I tried this on Windows and it worked without a problem. Therefore, I think this happens due to a permissions issue, environment variable issue or Java version/path related issue. However, I'm not that familiar with Java and I'm unable to isolate the exact cause.

Comment: Which version of Tomcat are you using?

Comment: apache-tomcat 10.0.12

Comment: Drop the WAR file into `webapps-javaee` and it should work. This will convert the application from Servlet 4.0 to Servlet 5.0 and deploy it. Most application need changes to work on Tomcat 10 (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66806582/11748454)).

Comment: This helped me to sort out the issue. Downgraded to apache-tomcat 8 and it works without issues now. Thank you!