# PHP JavaBridge.war is not working on tomcat 10 and says FAIL - Application at context path [/JavaBridge] could not be started

Tags: java, php, tomcat, centos

I am trying to run the PHP JavaBridge.war file by placing in wepapps folder and Deploying it from the manager tool but returned with the following error:

FAIL - Application at context path [/JavaBridge] could not be started

[image]

What could be the reason behind it?

Server: CentsOS 7
Tomcat: 10.0 Version

Comment: Put the WAR file into `webapps-javaee` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tomcat 10.0.4 doesn't load servlets (@WebServlet classes) with 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66806582/tomcat-10-0-4-doesnt-load-servlets-webservlet-classes-with-404-error)