# Tomcat subfolder webapp returning 404 error

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I developed a Webapp based on Java Servlet running on Tomcat. I make some test running Tomcat on my machine (localhost:port) directly using IntelliJ.

Now I need to publish my WebApp in another Tomcat Server where I need to put more than one app so my project is deployed in a subfolder and I can't understand how to solve 404 error: "The requested resource [/subfolder/servlet] is not available".

Tomcat is searching a servlet "/subfolder/servlet"...

Comment: What Tomcat version do you use?

Comment: Apache Tomcat/10.0.8

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/66808062/104891 look like your case? Does it work with Tomcat 9?

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem!
I add "web apps-javaee" folder in my Tomcat folder and then the app execution was fine