# Cannot deploy Tomcat web service

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, intellij-idea

I was trying to deploy a simple "helloWorld" web service with tomcat according to this tutorial:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-restful-web-service.html#new_project

and got this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ubTL.png)

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Post text rather than images

Comment: That tutorial uses Glassfish not Tomcat.  Tomcat is primarily a servlet/JSP JEE server where Glassfish and Wildfly are full JEE servers.  REST is part of the JAX-RS specification and is not, by default, included with Tomcat.

Comment: Try Tomcat 9, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66808062/104891.