# Tomcat 10.0.27 and IntelliJ V.2022.2.2 is giving me HTTP 404 on a new java project

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm starting a completely new project in IntelliJ v2022.2.2 but when I try to run it it shows the webpage ''Hello world'' and then when I click on the pregenerated link "Hello servlet" I'm getting this:

HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report
Message The requested resource [/webhusk_war_exploded/hello-servlet] is not available
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
Apache Tomcat/10.0.27

This is my settings for the new project:
Generators: Jakarta EE
Template: Web application
Application server: Tomcat 10.0.27
Language: Java
Build system: Maven
JDK: 19 oracle openJDK

> 

NEXT
Version: Java EE 8

If I change the version from Java EE 8 to Jakarta EE 9 it is working, but I need it to work in Java. Does anyone know if there is a bug somewhere in either IntelliJ or Tomcat that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project generated this way is incompatible with Tomcat 10, that's why you observe the 404 error. The cause of this problem is a [change Servlet API namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66806582/tomcat-10-0-4-doesnt-load-servlets-webservlet-classes-with-404-error/66808062#66808062) from javax.* (Tomcat 9) to jakarta.* (Tomcat 10).
If you want to continue using Java EE 8, I recommend you use Tomcat 9 instead 10.2.7.