# How to properly deploy war file in tomcat?

Tags: spring, api, tomcat, http-status-code-404, web-deployment

Im Deploying the .war in webapps, but at manager/html/WarFileName gives 404 error
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvtLW.png)

I have tried to check for logs, but catalina.out seems to be fine without any errors. Obvisouly even reaching the path with postman does not work.
Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by downgrade tomcat from version 10 to 8;
Tomcat 10 keep looking for jakarta packages, while my springboot app was still using Javax
[Tomcat 10.0.4 doesn't load servlets (@WebServlet classes) with 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66806582/tomcat-10-0-4-doesnt-load-servlets-webservlet-classes-with-404-error)