# I get a 404 error when requesting tomcat server in IntellijeIdea

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, tomcat, thymeleaf, http-status-code-404

I have a problem. I'm trying to set up a simple springMVC application, I do everything exactly according to the instructions, but for some reason everything always breaks for me.
this is git: https://github.com/Vlad1kavkaz/spring
This is my Dispatcher:

```
public class MySpringMVCDispather  extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {


    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {ApplicationContextMVC.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }
}
```

this is my Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("springcourse")
@EnableWebMvc
public class ApplicationContextMVC implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    public ApplicationContextMVC (ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }
}
```

This is my Controller:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @GetMapping("hello_world/")

    public String sayHello() {
        return "hello_world";
    }
}
```

The server starts, I can see the start page fine, but when I try to go to http://localhost:8080/hello_world I get an error:
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message The requested resource [/hello_world] is not available

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Everything I found on YouTube and here was for Eclipse or was about 8 years old, so it didn’t help in my case

I tried to do it through xml configuration, it didn’t help. There was the same error. I don’t know what to do, I just started learning to write a backend in Java, I used to do it in Python and it was much easier, but now nothing is clear. Help please

Here's something from the console, as I understand it these are logs:
"C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-9.0.83\bin\catalina.bat" run
[2023-11-29 11:23:21,940] Artifact spring-mvc-app1:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\28218\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2023.2\tomcat\406466cb-ef18-437d-a814-f1cdaccf9fd5"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-9.0.83"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-9.0.83\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Users\28218.jdks\openjdk-21.0.1"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-9.0.83\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-9.0.83\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Using CATALINA_OPTS:   ""
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
29-Nov-2023 23:23:23.796 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.83
29-Nov-2023 23:23:23.799 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Nov 9 2023 20:57:42 UTC
29-Nov-2023 23:23:23.799 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.83.0
29-Nov-2023 23:23:23.799 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 11
29-Nov-2023 23:23:23.800 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Р’РµСЂСЃРёСЏ РћРЎ:             10.0
29-Nov-2023 23:23:23.800 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log РђСЂС…РёС‚РµРєС‚СѓСЂР°:           amd64
29-Nov-2023 23:23:23.800 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Users\28218.jdks\openjdk-21.0.1
29-Nov-2023 23:23:23.801 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Р’РµСЂСЃРёСЏ JVM:            21.0.1+12-29
29-Nov-2023 23:23:23.801 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log РџСЂРѕРёР·РІРѕРґРёС‚РµР»СЊ JVM:     Oracle Corporation
29-Nov-2023 23:23:23.801 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\28218\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2023.2\tomcat\406466cb-ef18-437d-a814-f1cdaccf9fd5
29-Nov-2023 23:23:23.801 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-9.0.83
29-Nov-2023 23:23:23.802 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
29-Nov-2023 23:23:23.803 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
29-Nov-2023 23:23:23.803 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
29-Nov-2023 23:23:23.803 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
29-Nov-2023 23:23:23.803 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
29-Nov-2023 23:23:23.803 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\28218\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2023.2\tomcat\406466cb-ef18-437d-a814-f1cdaccf9fd5\conf\logging.properties
29-Nov-2023 23:23:23.804 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
29-Nov-2023 23:23:23.804 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
29-Nov-2023 23:23:23.804 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
29-Nov-2023 23:23:23.804 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
29-Nov-2023 23:23:23.805 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=C:\Users\28218\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2023.2\tomcat\406466cb-ef18-437d-a814-f1cdaccf9fd5\jmxremote.password
29-Nov-2023 23:23:23.805 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=C:\Users\28218\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2023.2\tomcat\406466cb-ef18-437d-a814-f1cdaccf9fd5\jmxremote.access
29-Nov-2023 23:23:23.805 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
29-Nov-2023 23:23:23.806 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
29-Nov-2023 23:23:23.806 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
29-Nov-2023 23:23:23.806 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
29-Nov-2023 23:23:23.806 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\28218\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2023.2\tomcat\406466cb-ef18-437d-a814-f1cdaccf9fd5
29-Nov-2023 23:23:23.807 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-9.0.83
29-Nov-2023 23:23:23.807 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-9.0.83\temp
29-Nov-2023 23:23:23.825 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Users\28218.jdks\openjdk-21.0.1\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Python39\Scripts;C:\Python39;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\bin;C:\Program Files\MATHLAB2323\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATHLAB2323\bin;C:\ffmpeg\bin;;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin;C:\Users\28218\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\28218\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.2\bin;;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2023.1.2\bin;C:\ffmpeg\bin;;C:\ffmpeg\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.2.2\bin;;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.5\bin;;C:\SFML-2.5.1\bin;C:\Users\28218.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.5\bin;;.]
29-Nov-2023 23:23:24.221 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Р�РЅРёС†РёР°Р»РёР·Р°С†РёСЏ ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
29-Nov-2023 23:23:24.257 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [841] milliseconds
29-Nov-2023 23:23:24.325 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
29-Nov-2023 23:23:24.325 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.83]
29-Nov-2023 23:23:24.345 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
29-Nov-2023 23:23:24.435 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [175] milliseconds
Connected to server
[2023-11-29 11:23:24,646] Artifact spring-mvc-app1:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
29-Nov-2023 23:23:25.130 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.setVersion Unknown version string [5.0]. Default version will be used.
29-Nov-2023 23:23:27.326 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
[2023-11-29 11:23:27,423] Artifact spring-mvc-app1:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2023-11-29 11:23:27,424] Artifact spring-mvc-app1:war exploded: Deploy took 2,778 milliseconds
29-Nov-2023 23:23:34.361 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory РЈСЃС‚Р°РЅРѕРІРєР° РІРµР± РїСЂРёР»РѕР¶РµРЅРёСЏ РІ РїР°РїРєСѓ [C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-9.0.83\webapps\manager]
29-Nov-2023 23:23:34.490 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-9.0.83\webapps\manager] has finished in [127] ms

Comment: Your mapping is `hello_world`, but you request `hello-world`.

Comment: doesn't matter, that's not the error, changed it - same thing

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub so that others can easily reproduce your issue and suggest a fix.

Comment: I corrected the question, but to make it easier, here is https://github.com/Vlad1kavkaz/spring

Comment: Your run configurations are missing from the shared project. Do you run it as a war on Tomcat? Note that you are using `jakarta` servlets, which are supported since Tomcat 10, but Tomcat 9 uses `javax` servlets. This could be the problem.

Comment: I used to write the backend only in Python and C++, I don’t fully understand what we’re talking about. Can you please tell me in more detail how to fix it?

Comment: Try running on Tomcat 10, you may have this issue, but the reverse of it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66808062/104891.

Comment: Thank you so much, you have no idea how much you helped me, I tried to solve this for two days, thank you very much)