# HTTP Status 404 – Not Found from apache tomcat 10

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat

I am trying to run a war file on tomcat 10 and getting "HTTP Status 404 – Not Found" error while accessing the homepage and any other page. I have double checked everything and configuration seems ok. Below are some of important details of project structure and code: -

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZE2G7.png)

web.xml

```
  <display-name>spring-mvc-example</display-name>

    <!-- Add Spring MVC DispatcherServlet as front controller -->
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
      org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>\WEB-INF\spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> 
  </servlet-mapping>
    
 </web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.springmvcexample.mvcexample" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF\views" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

HomeController.java

```
package com.example.springmvcexample.mvcexample;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.example.springmvcexample.model.User;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        System.out.println("Home Page Requested, locale = " + locale);
        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate);

        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String user(@Validated User user, Model model) {
        System.out.println("User Page Requested");
        model.addAttribute("userName", user.getUserName());
        return "user";
    }
}
```

I am trying to run a simple war file built and deployed using maven to tomcat server with multiple .jsp files. Below are the commands used to deploy the war file

.\mvnw tomcat7:deploy

and accessed using http://localhost:8080/myfirstapp/

Comment: I'm not saying this will solve all your problems - but look at where you have specified `WEB-INF\views` - and compare that with how it should be specified (look at the comment in the code, immediately preceding that line). Double-check where else you may have used a backslash (``\``), when you should have used a forward slash (`/`).

Comment: @andrewJames actually i replaced forward slash with back slash in first place as i was running program on windows so i thought it might work. Anyhow, above suggestion is not working.

Comment: @andrewJames please can you give guidance on how can debug this or any more suggestions what might solve the issue?

Comment: @VineetJain which spring version do you use?

Comment: "_above suggestion is not working_" - That is why I mentioned that this may not solve all your problems. It is probably a necessary step, but it is not the only step.

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos it's 4.3.9.RELEASE

Comment: @VineetJain why do you use `http://localhost:8080/myfirstapp/`? Where is the path `/myfirstapp/` configured?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tomcat 10.0.4 doesn't load servlets (@WebServlet classes) with 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66806582/tomcat-10-0-4-doesnt-load-servlets-webservlet-classes-with-404-error)

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz thanks it worked!! Also, i can see that 5.1.0.RELEASE version also compatible with tomcat 9.

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos the path is configured in build configurations in pom.xml

<plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
       <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.2</version>
       <configuration>
           <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
     <server>TomcatServer</server>
           <path>/myfirstapp</path>
       </configuration>
   </plugin>