# How to redirect path "/" to an arbitrary jsp file using servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have deployed my application (`todo.war`) into Tomcat v10.0.5. I expected that `http://localhost:8080/todo/` would bring me to `/jsp/index.jsp`, but I am getting a 404 response instead.

Here is my application's layout:

```
todo.war
├── META-INF
│   └── MANIFEST.MF
├── WEB-INF
│   ├── classes
│   │   └── com
│   │       └── ciaoshen
│   │           └── sia
│   │               └── demo
│   │                   └── gradle_demo
│   │                       └── todo
│   │                           ├── model
│   │                           │   └── ToDoItem.class
│   │                           └── web
│   │                               └── ToDoServlet.class
│   ├── lib
│   │   └── jstl-1.2.jar
│   └── web.xml
├── css
└── jsp
    ├── all.jsp
    └── index.jsp
```

So in `web.xml` file, servlet-mapping pattern `/` is bound to `ToDoServlet`,

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ToDoServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and `ToDoServlet.java` dispatched the path `/` to `/jsp/index.jsp` file.

```java
private String processRequest(String servletPath, HttpServletRequest request) {
    if (servletPath.equals("/")) {
        return "/jsp/index.jsp";
    } else if (servletPath.equals("/all")) {
        // ... other direction
    } else {
        // ... other direction
    }
}
```

but got `404` resource not found in browser,
[image]

my `index.jsp` is very simple,

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><title>First JSP</title></head>
<body>
    <h2>--- To Do Application ---</h2>
    <h2>Please make a choice:</h2>
    <h2><a href="/all">    (a)ll items</a></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone explain what I'm missing?

Comment: Since you are using Tomcat 10, are you using Servlet 5.0 (the classes, which start with `jakarta.servlet` instead of `javax.servlet`)? Check the logs for messages as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64117697/11748454).

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz problem solved when I switch dependencies to `jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api:5.0.0`. Thanks man!

Comment: @BalusC This is not a duplicate due to the nature of the problem.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Make your comment into an answer; I believe it is the correct one and should be accepted.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz: I also believe this question to be a duplicate (of all those questions caused by the jakartification process). If we consider duplicates two questions with the same symptoms, I tried to list 4 prototype duplicates in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66808062/11748454). The closest question to this one is probably _"X is not a jakarta.servlet.Servlet"_.