# Goal - http://localhost:8080/messenger/webapi/myresource => to get return "Got it!, but getting HTTP Status 404

Tags: java, xml, maven

1. How to resolve " java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.servlet.Filter - which is getting after running the server
2. Goal is to get a return as "Gotit" after application runnion on the server
3. Couple of solutions ask me to remove the web.xml file - the server is running fine but But not getting subject output.
4. The below link shows the code
5. Please advise how to resolve the issues as I'm trying to do a REST Web Services tutorial

[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ytw5R71i04i-1fPcFWootaxKri51qi1B/view?usp=sharing][1]

Thanks for your help

Comment: The first problem is most likely caused by two dependencies having different versions. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62927426/getting-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-jakarta-servlet-filter-on-maven-jersey

Comment: @Maurice The fact that it's `jakarta` absolutely means there's a mix of versions going on.

Comment: It would be useful if you could add the code in the question instead of linking the external Google Drive file.