# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/filter/LoggingFilter with jersey 2.35 and tomcat 9.0.55

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, jax-rs

I have web application with uses apache ant as build tool. I have place all the jars related to jersey-2.35 in the WEB-INF/lib directory.

jersey-2.35 uses jaxrs-2.1 as per this doc. https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey/download.html

I have placed all the jar which part of the bundle available in the WEB-INF/lib directory. I am able to successfully build the project but get this error during run time:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.init() for servlet [com.myproj.admin.ids.rest.OAuth2Application] threw exception
MultiException stack 1 of 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/filter/LoggingFilter
    at com.myproj.admin.ids.rest.OAuth2Application.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1356)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justCreate(Utilities.java:1059)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.create(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:968)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1072)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1064)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.createAndInitialize(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:194)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.createAndInitialize(ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.java:30)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationConfigurator.createApplication(ApplicationConfigurator.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationConfigurator.init(ApplicationConfigurator.java:72)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ApplicationHandler.java:294)
    at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.forEach(Arrays.java:3880)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:294)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:261)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:311)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:347)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1013)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5264)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1215)
    ... 54 more

Feb 28, 2022 4:03:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [com.myproj.admin.ids.rest.OAuth2Application] in web application [/nps] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1215)
    at com.myproj.admin.ids.rest.OAuth2Application.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1356)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justCreate(Utilities.java:1059)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.create(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:968)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1072)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1064)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.createAndInitialize(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:194)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.createAndInitialize(ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.java:30)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationConfigurator.createApplication(ApplicationConfigurator.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationConfigurator.init(ApplicationConfigurator.java:72)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ApplicationHandler.java:294)
    at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.forEach(Arrays.java:3880)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:294)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:261)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:311)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:347)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1013)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5264)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
```

Comment: I did go through this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62927426/getting-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-jakarta-servlet-filter-on-maven-jersey) but as the answer suggests i am already on jersey version 2.35

Comment: In 2.35, you should be using LoggingFeature, not LoggingFilter. If you are not explicitly using, then you have a dependency that is using. It that's the case, you should upgrade to a newer version of that dependency that uses a newer version of Jersey (preferable the same one you are using - or post-2.26).

Comment: Exactly, the logging feature has been deprecated & removed, see the [javadoc](http://javadox.com/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-common/2.23.2/org/glassfish/jersey/filter/LoggingFilter.html)

Comment: Thanks!! The comment really helped in understanding the issue.